# Matching multiple hex characters in a PGSQL Regex

Tags: regex, hex, psql

I'm trying to find some very specific multibyte characters in PostgreSQL using Regex. I know I have the option to make a long `CASE WHEN` but i decided to check if there is a different way to finding these.

My current Regex looks like this `E'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83'`
This works pretty well, except that I would need to find all from `\xf0\x9f\x98\x80` to `\xf0\x9f\x98\x99`.

In JS I would just be able to write something like `\xf0\x9f\x98[\x80-\x89]` but for whatever reason this returns an error in PGSQL. Is there a shortcut like this, or am I doomed to writing 20 `CASE WHEN`-s?

Comment: Try replacing `\x80` and `\x89` with literal symbols in the `[...]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, the idea seems good but I'm not very versed with multibyte characters. how am I supposed to do that? Could you explain please?

Comment: Are `\x80` and `\x89` multibyte chars? No idea, I just tried to guess.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I'm sorry, I didN't explain properly. `\xf0\x9f\x98\x83` is one special character. A smiley. I'm working on a function that would remove every 4 byte smiley like that from the database as they kill the printing.

Comment: It might be necessary to use 20 alternatives, like `\xf0\x9f\x98\x80|\xf0\x9f\x98\x81....|\xf0\x9f\x98\x89`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the help, but I just realized what I was doing wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have realized my mistake. PGSQL Error was caused because I'm looking for 4 byte characters and I just wanted to mess with the last byte. I realized I'd have to write it like this: `E'[\xf0\x9f\x98\x80-\xf0\x9f\x98\x90]'`